# How to parse a complex json using gson or jackson

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

The Json string looks something like this:

```
[
    {
         "Metric Payload": [
            {
                "MetaData": [
                    {
                        "FieldName": "PROC_PROC_ID",
                        "DataType": "UINT32",
                        "Label": "PID",
                        "Unit": "N/A"
                    },
                    {
                        "FieldName": "PROC_USER_NAME",
                        "DataType": "STRING",
                        "Label": "User Name",
                        "Unit": "N/A"
                    }
                ],
                "Instances": [
                    {
                        "PROC_INTEREST": "M",
                        "PROC_CPU_TOTAL_UTIL": "0.0",
                        "GBL_ACTIVE_CPU": "2"                        
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to parse and extract the value for "PROC_CPU_TOTAL_UTIL" which is present inside the "Instances" array. Tried below code, but it fails with Exception saying, NOT a JSON object.

```
    public String getmetrics(String jsonout) {
            String result = null;
            try {

                JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonout);         
                JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
                jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("");
                JsonArray jarray = jobject.getAsJsonArray("Instances");

                jobject = jarray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
                result = jobject.get("GBL_MEM_AVAIL").toString();
                System.out.println(result);



            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.err.println(e);
            }
            return result;


        }
```

Comment: where is GBL_MEM_AVAIL in json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer most brackets are misformated in your example. 
I'm not sure that's the root cause of your problem but `json` object are encapsulated within twirly brackets.
Lose the outermost square brackets to start...

Comment: or use `JsonElement.getAsJsonArray()` instead of `JsonElement.getAsJsonObject()`

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that GBL_MEM_AVAIL is missing (i suppose you left it out unintentionally), you have to follow the path of your JSon object. i.e. your are accessing Instances which is a child of Metric Payload.

so first get the payloads:

```
JsonArray payloads = jobject.getAsJsonArray("Metric Payload");
```

the the first intances on  payload:

```
JsonArray instances = payloads.get(0).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("Instances");
```

and then the fisrt occurance of instance:

```
jobject = instances.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
```

if you want to get all instances on all payloads you will have to introduce loops.

This is a valid json you can experiment with (copy paste to your editor):

```
public class TestJson {

  @Test
  public void testIt(){
    String x = "\n" +
      "    {\n" +
      "         \"Metric Payload\": [\n" +
      "            {\n" +
      "                \"MetaData\": [\n" +
      "                    {\n" +
      "                        \"FieldName\": \"PROC_PROC_ID\",\n" +
      "                        \"DataType\": \"UINT32\",\n" +
      "                        \"Label\": \"PID\",\n" +
      "                        \"Unit\": \"N/A\"\n" +
      "                    },\n" +
      "                    {\n" +
      "                        \"FieldName\": \"PROC_USER_NAME\",\n" +
      "                        \"DataType\": \"STRING\",\n" +
      "                        \"Label\": \"User Name\",\n" +
      "                        \"Unit\": \"N/A\"\n" +
      "                    }\n" +
      "                ],\n" +
      "                \"Instances\": [\n" +
      "                    {\n" +
      "                        \"PROC_INTEREST\": \"M\",\n" +
      "                        \"PROC_CPU_TOTAL_UTIL\": \"0.0\",\n" +
      "                        \"GBL_ACTIVE_CPU\": \"2\"                        \n" +
      "                    }\n" +
      "                ]\n" +
      "            }\n" +
      "        ]\n" +
      "    }\n" +
      "";
    getmetrics(x);
  }

  public void getmetrics(String jsonout) {
    String result = null;

    JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonout);
    JsonObject jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonArray payloads = jobject.getAsJsonArray("Metric Payload");
    JsonArray instances = payloads.get(0).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("Instances");
    jobject = instances.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
    System.out.println(jobject);
    result = jobject.get("PROC_CPU_TOTAL_UTIL").toString();
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```